# FIR amplitude response using Hr_type3 function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design

I am trying to design a type 3 FIR filter and generate its amplitude response from the function `Hr_type3` (mentioned in *Digital Signal Processing Using MATLAB* by J. Proakis), but getting an
**Error  : Unrecognized function or variable 'Hr_type3'.**

Can any one help me on this?

I am trying to build a digital differentiator from this code.

```
M = 21;
alpha = (M-1)/2;
n = 0:M-1;
hd = (cos(pi*(n-alpha)))./(n-alpha);
hd(alpha+1) = 0;
w_ham = (hamming(M))';
h = hd .* w_ham;
[Hr,w,P,L] = Hr_type3(h);
```

Comment: Do you have that Hr_type3() function available? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/2189/versions/1/previews/proakis/PWS_DSP/hr_type3.m/index.html

Comment: is it available in a particular library, i am trying to run it on matlab online or are you asking whether this fucntion is available on matlab ? @JuhaP

Comment: @dsp_psd: You should add the error message to your question. There is no obvious reason why this shouldn't work. Have you checked if that function is available in your environment?

Comment: @MattL. thanks for your feedback i updated the question and i am quite new to MATLAB so please can you tell how to check if the function is available in my environment , I am running MATLAB online under an academic license.

Comment: @dsp_psd: It looks like the function `Hr_type3` is not in your path. Make sure you have it available. If in doubt, just copy it into the directory you're working in. I suppose you realize that this function doesn't come with Matlab, but it's a specific function from the book.